# Removing css and js file from a page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I am using some css and js file on my master page.... I have a content page derived from that master page. Is it possible to remove some css or js file that in the master page and not needed in the content page.Can I remove those particular files fromcontent page....

thnks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Perhabs, this will help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95438/Changing-A-Master-Page-Body-Tag-s-CSS-Class-for-Di.aspx